# How to use 2 types of events in typescript interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to create a custom rest hook that has the parameter Event, and this parameter should be able to receive 2 types of Events - keyboard and mouse. I was trying to use union of types like `MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent` and it is not working :/

Any suggestions? Example below

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={query}
  onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
  onKeyDown={e => getUserPosition(e, query, assetType)}
/>

<Button
  fullWidth
  color="secondary"
  onClick={e => getUserPosition(e, query, assetType)}
>
  Search
</Button>
```

```
const getUserPosition = (
    e: MouseEvent & KeyboardEvent, <-- here is problem
    queryuery: string,
    assetType: AssetType
  ) => {
    if (e?.key === 'Enter') {
      // do something
    }

    if (e?.type === 'click') {
      //do something
    }
  }
```

Comment: try using ```e: Partial<MouseEvent & KeyboardEvent>```

Comment: ```Partial<T>``` is a very useful utility type offered by typescript and there are many more...https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype

Comment: @AshwynHorton it seems that function is okay with that, but when I want to use this the typings are wrong :/ 
"Argument of type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> & KeyboardEvent<Element>>'."

Comment: Okay hold on...lemme try provide a proper solution

Comment: Any reason why you simply don't write two handlers, one for each type of event? This would make your code easier to understand and handling different event types would be a non-issue. Alternatively, don't pass the event at all, do the extraction of the value in your arrow function and make the first argument of your handler a string.

Comment: It's odd that an event is both MouseEvent and KeyboardEvent at the same time. Usually I'd use `MouseEvent|KeyboardEvent` and then use a type guard to narrow down the type using a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is really an annoying and weird move from TypeScript. First you have to use the type `MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent` for the event since it come from an `onClick` callback **OR** an `onKeyDown` callback.

After you have to be sure what kind of event it is by checking for the presence of `e.key` for example

```js
const getUserPosition = (e: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) => {
  if (e.key) {
    // it's a KeyboardEvent 
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
    // do something
    }
  } else {
    // it's a MouseEvent 
    if (e.type === "click") {
      //do something
    }
  }
};
```

Problem then is that you got this error:

> Property 'key' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'

You have to use a valid check to be sure that this property `key` is present in the object `e`. You can use for that `"key" in e`:

```js
const getUserPosition = (e: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) => {
  if ("key" in e) {
    // it's a KeyboardEvent 
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
    // do something
    }
  } else {
    // it's a MouseEvent 
    if (e.type === "click") {
      //do something
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

let us take a look at what you have on the function definition first...:

so you want to parse one of two kinds of events in which one property may exist on one but not the other so let us look at this first approach...

```
/*
 * I Like your initial approach because it makes more logical sense this way,
 * only that you have to check if the property value you want to check is actually
 * in the value
 */
const getUserPosition = (e: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) => {
    if ('key' in e && e?.key === 'Enter') {
        // do something
    }

    if ('type' in e && e?.type === 'click') {
        //do something
    }
};
```

Comment: there is a small bug with `in` operator https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42771

Answer (score 0):

You can try next solution. Aka `strategy pattern`:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type ClickHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => any

const Button: FC<{ onClick: ClickHandler }> = () => <button onClick={e => e}></button>

const hasProperty = <T, P extends string>(obj: T, prop: P) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const isKeyboard = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>):
  e is React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> => hasProperty(e, 'key')

const isMouse = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>):
  e is React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> => hasProperty(e, 'type') && e.type === 'click'

const App: FC = () => {

  function getUserPosition(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): () => (query: string) => any
  function getUserPosition(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>): () => (query: string) => any
  function getUserPosition(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent> | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    return function (query: string) {
      const x = e;
      if (isKeyboard(e) && e.key === 'Enter') {

      }

      if (isMouse(e)) {
        //do something
      }

    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onKeyDown={e => getUserPosition(e)}
      />

      <Button
        onClick={e => getUserPosition(e)}
      >
        Search
</Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQLABQbMAnmEnIQDbA0AawASKAHYATfkihwAvHAAUSAFyJGMAHQBZCAFcAzkgCiANyQSYAHlEAVXQBkAQgZgwIE07JBWscPrGZpbWAHwAlIphcJKcbGxoXkbwbh5eGkQ2eF4CQsIaeSLi0rLyJDFKylEKMTYARu6eEnC5giIKOLy1cEgVNgD0jekSYQmsSRIpcAAWKEYAClQ8sJyKcDb22Au9AB4wVlJGcClQwBIA5mHKEPUAVhpbcGDLGgs1MQDy90gY2i8QTxcHjaOZGT4AdwkSwgKy42jQKH4-Bu92wALAEQA3ONJtNgEYANJITj1CAoKBSdaqDTIdA6Ymk8mUiz%20OyOJwASQkYHcPiQfnCcAAPpp6XpDCZWdZ2c40s1%20YKAkEpaEYJE1Gw4L04ASxX9GWSKVJpbYHM5ubyYIr-JUYmCYXDOKpsLRhCTaBFccl4ASVd0VOp9QySUaWWrZVyeXzfLaRcGJcFTZH5V4bdZsP7TRqtTq9XSDaHmSaI%20ao1b0%20rorN5o65FwXXRgUhPXAAGRt3raZuKBRKWhodrCFjsCY%20uAAQTAYEyxCqH1w4215AMEgwwC8cAuSBgAFUTFAFhAjMAYBuJDSE1nSxzU95YxnApKQraIhpqtXlABHAxyTgaU5zguBc4lzFc1zPTdtz3A8jxPSCLyDAsQyZY1kzLS0YwFV93wXb9fygf8ThgM5LhAiR4lYZdV3XKCd33OQ4NPc9L2QxNVTZMs70rTNn2zeM2MNYt0I5TDrQfdUohwXNtQYGADCgFpwNolp8L-ACSKAqSZO1OA8XgXZ1iQHEqN07VgHIFQCSE41VCiDsu3dNY%2037UxrDkVtpNHMztRIJcfIsqyjH9OztNMny4AGAYpAgE5qB3GYgJ03z-JS0y-O8uA5IU1SdJsMZwt0mxzitZLdK8RkABEIChTpuhiaCGMPY9mK8OyMoigYCrKmw7zK7U2nyOrq0a2CWoQ9qyoKiLtQAZVQKA0BmNhBjvaaiq63MvVYEggA)